# Proper location of log4j2.xml files within a tomcat webapp

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

We have a webapp that contains two `log4j2.xml` files:

- one within `WEB-INF/classes` containing webapp-specific logging settings *(1)*, and
- one within the root directory of a dependency located in `WEB-INF/lib` containing default logging settings that we use also in other webapps *(2)*

*My questions are:*

1. How does tomcat read and evaluate these files?
2. In which order are they read?
3. Is it possible to overwrite settings of *(2)* by *(1)* and how would I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the documentation [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html) you will find that:

> Log4j allows the configuration file to be specified in web.xml using the log4jConfiguration context parameter. Log4j will search for configuration files by:
>
> 1. If a location is provided it will be searched for as a servlet context resource. For example, if log4jConfiguration contains "logging.xml" then Log4j will look for a file with that name in the root directory of the web application.
> 2. If no location is defined Log4j will search for a file that starts with "log4j2" in the WEB-INF directory. If more than one file is found, and if a file that starts with "log4j2-name" is present, where name is the name of the web application, then it will be used. Otherwise the first file will be used.
> 3. The "normal" search sequence using the classpath and file URLs will be used to locate the configuration file.

if I understand correctly, this answers all your questions.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Assuming that a) `WEB-INF` contains both `classes` and `lib` and b) the "normal" search sequence ist the one described in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html, this would perfectly answer my question. So, summarized for my case that would mean that if `WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml` is present, this file would be used. And if this file does not exist, the first `log4j2.xml` file found within the root of one of the dependencies located in `lib` would be used (there should, of course, only be one such file). I'll go on with that.